# Relative Web path vs Absolute path

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

*this is a 3 part question*

Is there any performance or security risk in relative path ?

How can i convert relative path to absolute path [in a large project written in PHP] ?

in PHP when using `include` should i give the absolute path or the relative path ?

Comment: Are you asking about client-side paths in HTML / CSS / JavaScript or server-side ones in PHP?

Comment: it really depends on the location of your script. you can use `dirname(__FILE__);` to find  the current file absolute path. same for relatives path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of relative paths in PHP. Relative paths according to the filesystem start with `./` or `../` and do not impact performance. PHP also interprets relative paths like `what/ever.php` specially itself and takes the `include_path` into account for those. That's usually (measurably) slower since directories have to be traversed and searched.

Security, that's too broadly asked, does not directly play into that. And if there are possibly malicious include scripts placed elsewhere on the system and within the include_path, then I would consider that the actual problem, not the relative paths.

What you should use in your project, depends on if it needs to be relocatable. It's most common to simulate absolute paths using a constant ala `PROJECT_ROOT`.

To transform a filesystem-relative path into an absolute, use `realpath()`